# Get last value in list depending on specific item value in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue.js variable list and I want to get the last value of the list after filtered by an item value:

```
var users = new Vue({
  el: '#get-users',
  data: {
    items: [
      { id: 1, username: 'che', firstName: 'cheikh', group: 2 },
      { id: 1, username: 'lam', firstName: 'lamine', group: 1 },
      { id: 1, username: 'abd', firstName: 'abdoulaye', group: 1 },
      { id: 1, username: 'dem', firstName: 'demba', group: 3 },
      { id: 1, username: 'fat', firstName: 'fatou', group: 2 },
      { id: 1, username: 'pen', firstName: 'penda', group: 2 },
      { id: 1, username: 'olym', firstName: 'oly', group: 1 },
      { id: 1, username: 'aic', firstName: 'aicha', group: 1 },
    ]
  }
})
```

the items list is ordered by added_day(not appear here) . So I want to filter items by `group` and get the last value. Here if I filter by group:1, I should have

```
{ id: 1, username: 'aic', firstName: 'aicha', group: 1 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here i used vue `computed` to filter the group 1 items and get the last element of group 1 items.

```
data: {
    items: [
      { id: 1, username: 'che', firstName: 'cheikh', group: 2 },
      { id: 1, username: 'lam', firstName: 'lamine', group: 1 },
      { id: 1, username: 'abd', firstName: 'abdoulaye', group: 1 },
      { id: 1, username: 'dem', firstName: 'demba', group: 3 },
      { id: 1, username: 'fat', firstName: 'fatou', group: 2 },
      { id: 1, username: 'pen', firstName: 'penda', group: 2 },
      { id: 1, username: 'olym', firstName: 'oly', group: 1 },
      { id: 1, username: 'aic', firstName: 'aicha', group: 1 },
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    // a computed getter
    filteredLastItem: function() {

      // filtering based upon group 1 items...
      let getLastItem = this.items.filter(item => { return item.group == 1 })

      // fetching the last item...
      return getLastItem[getLastItem.length -1]
    }
  }
```

To check in html tags

```
<p>
  {{filteredLastItem}} 
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question completely, but this may work:

```
function getFilteredLast(group) {
  let filteredItems = data.items.filter(item => item.group === group)
  return filteredItems.length > 0
    ? filteredItems[filteredItems.length - 1];
    : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can Define a computed property for getting items with `group === 1`

```
computed: {
  group1 () {
    return this.items.filter(item => {
       item.group === 1
    })
  }
}
```

Then you can get last value of this computed property when you need it:

```
this.group1[this.group1.length - 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
var users = new Vue({
   el: '#get-users',
   data: {
      items: [
         { id: 1, username: 'che', firstName: 'cheikh', group: 2 },
         { id: 1, username: 'lam', firstName: 'lamine', group: 1 },
         { id: 1, username: 'abd', firstName: 'abdoulaye', group: 1 },
         { id: 1, username: 'dem', firstName: 'demba', group: 3 },
         { id: 1, username: 'fat', firstName: 'fatou', group: 2 },
         { id: 1, username: 'pen', firstName: 'penda', group: 2 },
         { id: 1, username: 'olym', firstName: 'oly', group: 1 },
         { id: 1, username: 'aic', firstName: 'aicha', group: 1 }
      ]
   },
   methods: {
      filteredUsersByGroup: function(group_value){
         var filtered = this.items.filter(function(user){
            return user.group == group_value;
         });
         return filtered[filtered.length-1]
      },
      filteredUsersByUsername: function(username_value){
         var filtered = this.items.filter(function(user){
            return user.group.toLowerCase().indexOf(username_value.toLowerCase())>=0;
         });
         return filtered[filtered.length-1]
      }
   }
})
```

You can use `computed:{}` too